# Найти следующее меньшее число с такими же цифрами

Tags: python

На вход подается число, состоящее из n цифр, надо найти предыдущее число с таким же набором цифр, **например**:
12354 - 12345,
21 - 12,
511 - 151.
Если найти не удается, вывести -1, **например**:
9 - (-1),
222 - (-1),
500 - (-1) *так как ноль будет не значащим, что противоречит условию.*

```py
import itertools as iter

def next_smaller(number):
    digits = [digit for digit in str(number)]
    all, l = list(iter.permutations(digits)), -1
    for i in range(len(all)):
        if int(''.join(all[i])) < number and ''.join(all[i]).startswith('0') != True:
            l = int(''.join(all[i])) if int(''.join(all[i])) > l else l
    return l
```

**Такой вариант работает, но нужно быстрее**

```py
def next_smaller(number):
    l = -1
    for numberr in range(number - 1):
        if sorted([digit for digit in str(number - numberr)]) == sorted([digit for digit in str(number)]):
            if numberr < number and str(number - numberr).startswith('0') != True:
                l = number - numberr if number - numberr > l else l
    return l
```

**Такой вообще тормозит на 10^9 числах**

**Наверняка чисел будет много, найти нужно наибольшее из них - то есть самое близкое к оригинальному числу**

Я так понимаю все дело во времени перебора всех чисел, или их комбинаций как в 1 примере, помогите упростить код.

Comment: берете последнюю цифру и ищете первую с конца большую . и их меняете ?

Comment: а на примере можно?

Comment: код писать лень, а так 92344762172133 - берем предпоследнее 3, ближайшее большее 7 -> 9234476232173 - не оно?

Comment: @splash58 чёта оно у тебя укоротилось...

Comment: единичку потерял - руками писал. в принципе, нас часть левее той семерки не интрересует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищется с конца первая цифра такая, что правее есть хотя бы одна цифра меньше. Далее перемещается - наибольшая из тех, что меньше её и правее - на её место, остальные в конце в порядке убывания. Особая ситуация - цифра такая, что правее есть хотя бы одна цифра меньше, первая в числе, а все цифры меньше её - нули, тогда решения нет, ибо ведущий ноль запрещён.

Применительно к числу, показанному в комментарии [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58) - `92344762172133`:

Первая справа цифра, отвечающая требованиям - это четвёртая с конца двойка. Правее неё цифры `1,3,3`. Максимальная из них меньше этой двойки - 1. Остаются цифры `3,3 и 2`. Результат `92344762171332`.

В код это превращайте без меня... я с питоном на "ой, а что это?".

Comment: написал костыльный код, сработало, спасибо!